# Are phrases like "This thesis develops" good writing style?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, writing-style

`Hi,

I am writing my thesis. In this thesis I am using the phrases "this thesis develops a new method for..."

I am not sure if this is considered a good writing style or even wrong.

What I don't like about this phrase is that implies that the thesis itself literally did somthing actively which it did not; it's just a collection of sentences.

An alternative phrase would be "I develop in this thesis a new method..." or "In this thesis a new methods is developed".
The first phrase sounds to subjective to me. I would like to avoid using "I" in a scientific context.
The second phrase is passive voice which also might not be good writing style.

What is you opionon on this matter? What would be the prefered way to phrase such a sentence in a scientific thesis?

Thank you!

Comment: A safe bet is to look at the wording in other theses in your field. You might  add a few words to be more specific, e.g. "This thesis documents the development of a new method..." Or some short description of *what you cover*. Is it the theoretical basis of the method? The development process? Applications? Everything? If your title is "A new method for..." your bare sentence doesn't add much info.

Comment: Do you have a faculty advisor as you write your thesis? I agree that it's nice to prefer active constructions to passive, and probably preferable to avoid "I" in a science context. But if you do in fact lay out a "new method for ___" in your thesis, I don't see the problem with "this thesis develops." Yes, it's "just a collection of sentences," but it conveys information. Perhaps you would feel more comfortable with "this thesis *documents*," or "*describes* a new method for."

Comment: **This thesis presents or introduces a new method for/of** etc.

Comment: Don't be too literal about an animated thesis with agency, no one else will object: This book addresses, my watch says, and the time has arrived.